# Chrome hides element that shouldn't be effected

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, hidden

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sthsuuec/1/) of my problem, and a code snippet in case that doesn't work:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).append("<div id='xxx'>ccc</div>")
    },
    function() {
      $('#xxx').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <a href="xxx">
          <img src="xxx">aaa
        </a>
        bbb
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I hover out of div, Text part of the link `aaa` **disappears**. I becomes `:hover{visibility:visible}` for some reason.
It has nothing to do with elements ids or text or links.
It is Chrome problem, Firefox works as should.

Is it a bug or it is a js problem here? Why does Chrome do that?

Comment: Works for me - Chrome 44.0.2403.130

Comment: 45.0.2454.101 m, and I am not the only one who sees that problem

Comment: @Qiao No, I've also having the same problem, weird ^,~

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Chrome version?

Comment: it seems to be new version bug

Answer (score 2):

Surrounding 'bbb' with `span` fixes the problem:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).append("<div id='xxx'>ccc</div>")
    },
    function() {
      $('#xxx').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <a href="xxx">
          <img src="xxx">aaa
        </a>
        <span>bbb</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use it for now as a quick patch

Comment: @Qiao To be honest, it's not really a patch; the error is caused due to invalid syntax. You can't expect jQuery to be prepared for every case, and this is one of it's uncaught exceptions. Gecko handles it as expected because it doesn't apply any properties to the text, it's like when you view a php file locally, you just see the text. Whereas Webkit tries to make sense of what you've given it and applies some properties to it, which confuses jQuery. I haven't got any sources for this so correct me if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

user after method to solve this problem

```
<script>
$('div').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).after("<div id='xxx'>ccc</div>")
    },
    function() {
        $('#xxx').remove();
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: I wasn't looking a way to solve this problem, you just can do it differently in many ways. `append` and `after` are not the same after all, I had to change other parts of my code. I need to know what was wrong with my code. But you can reply that it is a chrome bug and I will accept it ) It really is.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
$('div').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).parent().append("<div id='xxx'>ccc</div>");
    },
    function() {
        $('#xxx').remove();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting behaviour. I've tried to add this, and text part of `aaa` is showing.

```
function(){
        $(this).clearfix:after {
        /* visibility: hidden; */}}
```

Comment: A clearfix is a way for an element to automatically clear its child elements, so that you don't need to add additional markup.